# Bitwise operations but what is the meaning (Espruino)

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

What is the meaning of this line of code

```
n = (n<<1) | ((d>=0.0004)?1:0);
```

Trying to understand code from here in function sigOff()
http://www.espruino.com/Remote+Control+Sockets

Comment: Shift `n` one bit left (the same as `* 2`); then locical `OR` that value with bit one set to `1` if the expression `d>=0.0004` is true. So if `n` is `000010100111b` and `d` is `0.0004` `n` will be `0000101001111b`. [Read about bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet seems to use the [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) OR (`|`) and left shift (`<<`) operators:

> Bitwise OR: `a | b`;
>   *Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either or both operands are ones.*
>   Left shift: `a << b`;
>   *Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeros from the right.*

The left shift by `1` (`<< 1`) basically doubles the value of `n`.
Then, the or (`|`) basically "adds" `1` to the result to make it uneven, if `d >= 0.0004`.
If `d < 0.0004`, the result from the left shift isn't changed.

So, for `n == 3` and `d == 0.0004`, this happens:

```
n << 1          // 6
(d>=0.0004)?1:0 // 1
6 | 1           // 7
```

For `n == 5` and `d == 0.0002`, this happens:

```
n << 1          // 10
(d>=0.0004)?1:0 // 0
10 | 0          // 10
```